# I get Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I am new in node js and I stack with this error longtime.
Can someone help me to find a solution!
here is the code taht I have written !

```
router.get('/list',function (req, res, next)
{
   res.render('listaccounts.ejs',{mybalance:mybalance});
 });
 //accounts creation
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
var passphrase = req.body.passphrase;
var mybalance=web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance(web3.eth.accounts[0]));
var accountAddress=web3_.personal.newAccount("passphrase",function(error,result){

   if(!error){
    console.log(result);
             }
   else {
    res.render('error.ejs');
       }
    });


res.redirect('/accounts/list');

  });
```

Comment: The problem is exactly as it says. You have already sent the headers, you can not modify them now. You must modify headers before sending _any_ content to the server, as the headers are one of the first things over the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Jakub said. Also you maty have an async execution problem (you don't know what will execute first, the redirect or the render). I think you could simply:

```
var accountAddress=web3_.personal.newAccount("passphrase",function(error,result){

   if(!error){
    console.log(result);
    res.redirect('/accounts/list');
   }
   else {
    res.render('error.ejs');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lays in

```
    if(!error){
    console.log(result);
             }
   else {
    res.render('error.ejs');
       }
    });


res.redirect('/accounts/list');
```

When it catches else statement, it does render the page, then you call page redirect, but headers were sent during res.render.
In short words, you can't render and redirect at the same time